# Php, runkit, adding new method -> apache crashes

Tags: php, runkit

I have an abstract class with a method what I want to invoke:

```
abstract class KLASS
{
    protected function pr()
    {
        return 'pr()';
    }
}
```

since I cant even instantize that, I create a layer on it:

```
class KLASS2 extends KLASS
{
}
```

so:

```
$a = new KLASS2();

runkit_method_rename ('KLASS', 'pr', 'pr_old');
runkit_method_add ('KLASS', 'pr', '', 'var_dump (method_exists($this, "pr")); var_dump (method_exists($this, "pr_old")); return $this->pr_old();', RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC);

echo $a->pr();
```

So what Im doing? I rename the old `pr()` function to `pr_old()` and add a new `pr()` with public access instead. This new `pr()` calls the old `pr()` routine, and this causes apache crashes. Please dont tell me to just edit the classes, I have to leave all classes untouched.

The most interesting part is, if `pr()` is **private**, it all **works** well!

Comment: can you try with : "runkit_method_redefine( string $classname , string $methodname , string $args , string $code [, int $flags = RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC ] )" ?

Comment: unfortunately no. It might work, but Im using unit testing, and by redefining, old codes will be "uncovered"